# Download jupyter notebook from VM Instance that does not open anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I created a VM Instance on Google Cloud. Using the GPUs of this instance, I ran several experiments on Google AI Platform in a Jupyter notebook.

Now I can not start the instance anymore, since weeks I get the error that the time zone has run out of resources.  However, without starting the instance I can not open the Jupyter notebooks, hence I can not download them and all my work and code is currently unavailable.

I know I could try to move the instance to a different time zone, but this seems like a tedious solution. How can I obtain those notebooks?

Comment: Can you try first deattaching the GPU and check if the VM instance can be started? If not, you can create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the persistent disk attached to your Notebook, then [create a VM instance from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) and access SSH to try to recover the notebooks. These tasks could be also a bit tedious, but you need to evaluate if you are willing to perform something like this to recover the info.

Comment: In addition, you might want to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#support_plans_overview) and open a ticket since several weeks without resources seems unusual.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with de-attaching the GPU. Super obvious solution and I haven't thought of it. It worked. So I downloaded the work and created a new instance on a different time zone. Thank you @rsantiago

Comment: You're welcome @XsLiar, I'm adding it as an Answer to give more visibility and you might want to upvote it if it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of workarounds that can help.

- Deattach the GPU from the VM instance and check if the VM instance can be started, but if not:
- You can create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the persistent disk attached to your VM Notebook, and [create a VM instance from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot), then access through SSH to try to recover the notebooks.

These tasks could be also a bit tedious, but you need to evaluate if you are willing to perform something like this to recover the info. In addition, you might want to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#support_plans_overview) and open a ticket since several weeks without resources seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Even if  you have the quota that doesn't mean that you will get the [resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#quotas_and_resource_availability) all the time. If you received an error like notfound or does not exist in [zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#zone_availability) then See [Regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) to find out which features are available in each zone.

For now, unfortunately you need to keep try in to move the instance in different regions to get access in to those.

You also can [Chat online](https://cloud.google.com/contact#) with our Google Cloud sales team in order to get more information.

Chat is available Monday, 9 AM ET, through Friday, 7 PM ET